# Linux ping network namespace

Tags: linux, networking, ping

I added namespace to my host-machine and made it available by using this:

```
ip netns add h1
ip link add veth01 type veth peer name veth1
ip link set dev veth1 netns h1
ifconfig veth01 10.0.0.1/24 up
ip net e h1 ifconfig veth1 10.0.0.2/24 up
route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.0.0.1 dev veth01
ip net e h1 ip r a default via 10.0.0.1
```

Now I can ping 10.0.0.2 from my host and backward (    ip net e h1 ping 10.0.0.1    ).

Then I did the same with the second namespace:

```
ip netns add h2
ip link add veth02 type veth peer name veth2
ip link set dev veth2 netns h2
ifconfig veth02 20.0.0.1/24 up
ip net e h2 ifconfig veth2 20.0.0.2/24 up
route add -net 20.0.0.0/24 gw 20.0.0.1 dev veth02
ip net e h2 ip r a default via 20.0.0.1
```

Now e.g. I can ping 10.0.0.1 (and 20.0.0.1) from h1 (10.0.0.2); can ping 20.0.0.2 from host, but I can't ping 20.0.0.2 from h1. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you checked firewall rules?

Comment: @NickW iptables said that all policies are 'accept' if you mean this

Answer (score 2):

> What am I doing wrong?

Adding route — it's wrong because you've assigned this network per interface pair already.

```
ifconfig veth01 10.0.0.1/24 up
…
route add -net 10.0.0.0/24 gw 10.0.01 dev veth01
```

Another possible culprit people often tend forgetting is enabling forwarding per se (`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1`).

Answer (score 0):

The answer is that network namespaces are completely separate. You will need to link the two namespaces so that traffic that comes from outside is forwarded. There are a few ways to do that. The easiest way is to create a bridge between the two `veth` devices.

At the moment, what you're seeing is that from `host-machine` you can ping both local addresses (10.0.0.1 and 20.0.0.2) but only 10.0.0.2 knows abut the existence of 10.0.0.1. To get 20.0.0.1 to respond, you need to be sure that your pings are either coming from the same network (20.0.0.0/24 although this is not a final solution) or that there is some sort of connection between the namespace and the default routing tables.

Comment: The problem was that loopbacks were down(

Comment: namespaces are separate but then you have 2 endpoints of same veth in system, and custom NS. You don't need no bridging to get simple forwarding between working.

Answer (score 0):

1. By default the loopback interface of created network namespace is down. It should be activated with command `ip ns exec <NSNAME> ip link set up dev lo`.
2. Check the routing (`sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward`). It should be enabled. Check the actual routes with `ip route get 20.0.0.2 from 10.0.0.2 iif veth01` and vice versa. It should be return a valid route.
3. Check the firewall rules with `iptables-save -c`. Allow packets between `veth` interface in the `filter/FORWARD` chain.

#### Full configuration

- Create the `h1` namespace

```
ip netns add h1
```

- Create veth pair of interfaces for the `h1` namespace

```
ip link add veth_h1 type veth peer name veth_main
```

- Move the `veth_main` interface into the `h1` namespace

```
ip link set dev veth_main netns h1
```

- Configure the `veth_h1` interface

```
ip link set dev veth_h1 up
ip address add 10.0.0.1/24 dev veth_h1
```

- Configure network inside the `h1` namespace

```
ip netns exec h1 ip link set dev lo up
ip netns exec h1 ip link set dev veth_main up
ip netns exec h1 ip address add 10.0.0.2/24 dev veth_main
ip netns exec h1 ip route add 0/0 via 10.0.0.1 dev veth_main
```

- And similar steps for the `h2` namespace in the `main` namespace

```
ip netns add h2
ip link add veth_h2 type veth peer name veth_main
ip link set dev veth_main netns h2
ip link set dev veth_h2 up
ip address add 10.20.0.1/24 dev veth_h2
```

- And inside of the `h2` namespace

```
ip netns exec h2 ip link set dev lo up
ip netns exec h2 ip link set dev veth_main up
ip netns exec h2 ip address add 10.20.0.2/24 dev veth_main
ip netns exec h2 ip route add 0/0 via 10.20.0.1 dev veth_main
```

- Check the routing

```
~$ ip r g 10.20.0.2 from 10.0.0.2 iif veth_h1
10.20.0.2 from 10.0.0.2 dev veth_h2 
    cache iif veth_h1 

~$ ip r g 10.0.0.2 from 10.20.0.2 iif veth_h2
10.0.0.2 from 10.20.0.2 dev veth_h1 
    cache iif veth_h2
```

#### Notes

- To remove the veth pair of interfaces enough remove the master interface :

```
ip link del dev veth_h1
```

- To move back an interface from some namespace to the main namespace:

```
ip netns exec h2 ip link set dev veth_main netns 1
```

**P.S.** Forget about `ifconfig`, because it's deprecated.